# How to draw 2D pixel data with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rendering, opengl-es, sdl2

I am fairly new to OpenGL. I have a 2D game in SDL2 that uses currently works by creating a `SDL_Surface` from the pixel data, copying it into a `SDL_Texture`, and rendering it to the screen with `SDL_Renderer`. But rather than using SDL to render the pixels, I'd like to switch to OpenGL. The reason I'd like to switch is because I need to render some lines on top of the pixel data and `SDL_RenderDrawLine()` just doesn't have all the features I need (like line thickness or `glScissor`). At first, I attempted to switch to OpenGL by using `glDrawPixels()` and I was happy with the results. However, I found out that `glDrawPixels()` does not seem to be available in OpenGL-ES (mobile devices). I have looked through some tutorials, but they all use shaders and other fancy stuff that I don't think I really need. Is there a simple way (like `glDrawPixels()`) to just draw pixel data to the screen for a 2D game? The pixel data is in the format `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and it contains everything that I want to draw on the screen (except for several 2D line segments that I plan on using GL to render on top).

Comment: OpenGL for mobiles require Shaders for almost everything... Personally I'm not really sure of another way to do work there.

Comment: Why not use models and textures?

Comment: As a side comment OpenGL ES does not neccesarily support lines wider than one pixel. It is left in the API mainly for debugging. Go for triangles instead if possible.